# Are the names of these months realistic?

Tags: language-evolution, time, calendarium

I'm working on a calendar. To choose the name of the months I focused on Latin and in particular on a systematisation of the names finishing with 'ber'. I was wondering if my choices were correct and realistic.
For example, the name of the twelfth month is too long so if you think you know how it would have evolved in English, I'm interested.

1. Premember
2. Secember
3. Tertiember
4. Quatember
5. Quintember
6. Sextember
7. September
8. October
9. November
10. December
11. Undecember
12. Duodecember

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In addition to the familiar *September–December*, there were two more numerically named months before they were renamed in early imperial era: *Quintilis* and *Sextilis*.
These should definitely go to your slots 5 and 6.
In English you could call these Quintile and Sextile.

You seem to have slightly misanalyzed the ending.
What you add to the end of a number is not *-ember* but *-ber*.
This is an easy mistake to make, as three of the four usual month numbers (*septem*, *octo*, *novem*, *decem*) end in *-em*.
The key observation is that we have October, not Octember.

It appears that the numbers 7–10 get the ending *-ber* to the cardinal number, whereas 5–6 get the ending *-ilis* to the (stem of the) ordinal number.
That is, *Quin(c)tilis* and *Sextilis* seem to be based on *quintus* and *sextus*, not *quinque* and *sex*.
So, there are two attested ways to produce month names from numbers.

To me it sounds more natural to use the ordinal one for the first months:

1. *primus > Primilis*
2. *secundus/alter > Secundilis/Altrilis*
3. *tertius > Tertilis* (somehow *Tertiilis* sounds unnatural)
4. *quartus > Quartilis*

*Tertilis* and *Quartilis* (or Tertile and Quartile in English) sound quite natural to me, but the first two less so.
However, they feel more understandable and Latin to me than the ones you proposed.
With this pattern the first half of the year has *-ilis*, the second half has *-ber*.

I find no way around the somewhat clumsy *Undecember* and *Duodecember*.
As Draconis points out in another answer, the Latin numbers 11 and 12 are *undecim* and *duodecim*, so maybe you could change the month names to Undecimber and Duodecimber.
However, it would not be unreasonable to keep the *-e-* by analogy in the English versions.
I don't know whether adding *-ber* in Latin would change the vowel or whether later developments in English would naturally lead to a vowel change, but this is just a minor detail.
One practical benefit of the *-i-* is that it sets the eleventh and twelfth month apart from December.
The names [*undecimber* and *duodecimber*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecimber) are used for the thirteenth and fourteenth month in some contexts, such as computing.

An option worth serious consideration is having the year start in March instead of January.
This is what the Roman calendar did, and this is why the names are off by two.
This would have the benefit of the months names aligning with the ones already in use.

Here is the suggested list in English resulting from the considerations above:

1. Primile
2. Altrile or Secundile
3. Tertile
4. Quartile
5. Quintile
6. Sextile
7. September
8. October
9. November
10. December
11. Undecember or Undecimber
12. Duodecember or Duodecimber

Comment: In computing, the thirteenth month is called UNDECIMBER. It is used to give an easy way to refer to (and thus specify) the names of months in calendars in which a year has thirteen months - or in which some years do. [This Wikipedia article is concise and reasonably sensible][1]


  [1]: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecimber

Answer (score 10):

To supplement Joonas's wonderful answer, the words for "eleven" and "twelve" in Latin are *undecim* and *duodecim*, with an *i*. So I would suggest those months be changed to *Undecimber* and *Duodecimber*.

Comment: Good point! I upgraded my answer a bit. I would find it reasonable to keep the *e* in the English versions by analogy. I don't really know whether the *-ber* would have an effect on the vowel in Latin.

Comment: I would *strongly* prefer "Undecember" and "Duodecember" rather than using forms ending in "-decimber", both because of the analogy of "September", &al., and the fact the reduction of the "e" to "i" in _undecim_ would not naturally occur in a heavy syllable, as in _Undec(e/i)mber_.

Comment: @varro Does vowel reduction not happen in heavy syllables? I thought it happened to short vowels no matter what came after them.

Comment: I probably should have been more precise in my comment.  Compare _accipere_ with _acceptus_ - the second vowel in each exhibits a type of vowel reduction, but the closed syllable in _acceptus_ prevents the last stage in the full progression of /a/ -> /e/ -> /i/, which is at issue here.  That said, the various numbers ending in _-decim_ seem to be somewhat irregular in that we should expect to see forms such as *_undicem_, &c. rather than _undecim_.